# Flashing TP-Link TL-WR1043ND ver 2.x with DD-WRT

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I noticed that after buying the device, there exists only binaries for 1.x. 
I did not find any successful attempt about installing binaries of 1.x to the device 2.x. 
The precise name of my device is TL-WR1043ND Ver 2.1, while you can find only binaries of 1.x [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).
I tried unsuccessfully for instance the binary TP-Link TL-WR1043N(D) 1.x v24 PreSP2 [Beta] Build: 21061.

TP-Link TL-WR1043ND Ver 2.1 which I bought

[image]

TP-Link TL-WR1043ND Ver 1.x
[image]

### Flashing ver 2.x with beta drivers 2.x

I found the discussion [Flashing DD-WRT on your TP-Link TL-WR1043ND v2.1](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2015/01/flashing-dd-wrt-on-your-tp-link-tl.html) by searching the filename in the [first answer](https://superuser.com/a/1025672/2005). [Here](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2015/01-04-2015-r25760/tplink_tl-wr1043nd-v2/) beta drivers 2015. 
I do router reset by holding the reset button 30 seconds. Turn off and hold for 30 seconds. Turn on and hold reset button for 30 seconds. 
I go to System Tools > Firmware Upgrade and upload the file *tplink_tl-wr1043nd-v2.bin* but get

```
Error code: 18005
Upgrade unsuccessfully because the version of the upgraded file was incorrect. Please check the file name.
```

This error is because of flashing the first time with wrong drivers. 
You need to flash with the file instead *factory-to-ddwrt.bin* for the first time in the router. 
Now, I am thinking if I need to flash once again with *tplink_tl-wr1043nd-v2.bin*. No because the file size of two files are equal so only minor changes between files. Please, correct me if I am wrong. 
Go to 192.168.1.1 and you see DD-WRT GUI.

---

How can you install the DD-WRT drivers of TP-Link TL-WR1043ND Ver 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official releases of drivers are now available [here](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WR1043ND_V2.html#Firmware) if you do not want to use DD-WRT beta drivers. I could not find stable DD-WRT drivers for the device.

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct drives, If found these for the Tplink tl-wr1043nd 2.1.
ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2014/06-23-2014-r24461/tplink_tl-wr1043nd-v2/

Sincerely, Kteckca (Keaton)

Comment: I gave you the bounty because you found the betas for the router.